# How to call a function on button click in react js?

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick

I need to call a function when button is clicked.
my code is:

```
    createButtonsArray(arr){
         return arr.arr.map((key,index) =>
         <input type='button' onClick={this.sayHello}/>
    )}

    sayHello() {
        alert('Hello!');
    }
```

now, I get an error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'sayHello' of undefined
```

what could it be?

Comment: This is a binding issue, you need to either make `sayHello` and `createButtonsArray` a property with a value of an arrow function. Or you could call `this.sayHello = this.sayHello.bind(this)` in your constructor (same for `createButtonsArray`).

Comment: Is this in a functional component? `this` is undefined in functional components. Otherwise you need to bind `this` to the `sayHello` function in class-based components, either in the constructor, or by converting it to an arrow function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
class Comp {
  constructor() {
    this.sayHello = this.sayHello.bind(this);
    this.createButtonsArray = this.createButtonsArray.bind(this);
  }

  sayHello() {
    alert("Hello!");
  }
  createButtonsArray(arr) {
    return arr.arr.map((key, index) => (
      <input type="button" onClick={this.sayHello} />
    ));
  }
}
```

OR

If you want to bind this

```
class Comp {
  sayHello = () => {
    alert("Hello!");
  }

  createButtonsArray = (arr) => {
    return arr.arr.map((key, index) => (
      <input type="button" onClick={this.sayHello} />
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I did as your first suggestion, it worked! now I need to 'write' over each button value of key, how would I do that?

Comment: `<button onClick={() => this.sayHello(key, index)}> {key}</button>` use like this

Comment: I used value={key} at the end, but thank you so much.